# Javascript disable/enable event and $addhandler

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am fairly new to JScript and I am looking for a way to subscribe to the event when a textbox is disabled or enabled.  I am creating a AJAX Extender Control and I am subscribing through the JScript:

```
$addhandler(textbox, 'EventName', Function);
```

I have it working for `click`, `focus` and `blur`, but I'd like to get enable disable working.
Is there an exhaustive list of events that can be hooked into out there? I've tried Googling everything I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any simple solution to this.

Firstly, there are two properties for form elements which you may want to look at: [disabled](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp) and [readonly](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp). They both behave differently.

Secondly, there is no specific browser event that will trigger when those properties are changed. [PPK has a good list of events and their browser support](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html). The closest you can come is something like the funky `DOMAttrModified` or `DOMSubtreeModified` - but I don't think these work across all browsers.

Comment: Wow, there are a lot of No's next to those two events.  Looks like I'll have to find another way around this.  Good to know there's a good reference for these situations though.  Thanks.