# Add event handler when checkbox becomes disabled

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Is there a way to add an event handler (like `.on('change' ..)` to a checkbox when it becomes disabled?

I tried this (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G2Pue/1/)), but it does not fire when I disable the checkbox:

```
$('#myCB').on('change', function() {
     console.log('checkbox disabled? ' + $('#myCB').is(':disabled'));
});

$('#myCB').prop('disabled', true); // does NOT trigger the function above
```

*Edit:* I want to add the logic to the checkbox only because in my application I don't know when the checkbox might become disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I just found this nice way to trigger the change event every time the properties change:

```
var oldProp = $.fn.prop;
var newProp = function() {
    // console.log('$(..).prop() called');
    // execute jQuery's .prop() method
    var retFunc = oldProp.apply(this, arguments);
    // afterwards trigger custom event
    this.trigger('property_changed', this);
    return retFunc;
}
// replace jQuery's .prop() function with the new one
$.fn.prop = newProp;
```

Now every time I call `.prop()` on any element it will automatically trigger my custom change event. See the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G2Pue/5/).

**Edit**: As rahul maindargi mentioned in his comment it is better to use a custom event instead of the "change" event itself. I have updated my code so that it uses custom events now.

Comment: this is a very good way.. only thing is it will be triggered only if the property change happens with jquery... not with simple javascript.

Comment: Yes, but since I am using jQuery in my whole application and don't use any other "pure js" framework, I can safely use this method.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way should be:

```
$('#myCB').prop('disabled', true).triggerHandler('change');
```

Comment: But that would mean I have to manually trigger the event everywhere where I disable the checkbox. Is there no way to automatically get to know when the property changed?

Comment: There are observers but not available on all browsers or you need to add some javascript libraries. You could create your own custom event too.

Answer (score 1):

The [change](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event gets fired when the value of the field changes (so when the checkbox gets checked). It does not work on the disabling.

Firing an event on disabling the checkbox might be tricky to do. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763386/javascript-disable-enable-event-and-addhandler).

Comment: Thank you for the link. :) Now I know it can't be done the way I planned it. :)

Comment: Update: Using jQuery it's actually not that tricky to fire an event when the checkbox becomes disabled.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you want to listen to DOM mutation events. You can do that by DOM mutation event as any normal javascript event such as a mouse click.

Refer to this : http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MutationEvent

Example:

```
$("element-root").bind(DOMSubtreeModified,"CustomHandler");
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm not sure I want to do that though. It sounds kind of complicated so I guess I'll stick to manually triggering the "change" event. ;)

Comment: If you are going to `manually` trigger, atleast use `custom event` in Jquery. if you use change it can be problematic if ever you want to listen to actual change event

Comment: Very good point rahul! I have modified my answer taking your comment into account. Thank you.